# Ubuntu Intel i5 processor performance

Tags: 13.04

I've noticed very bad performance on my Intel i5 / 8gb machine.
Here is what the processor activity looks like.

Every time I run another applications the processor changes to the next one.
I creating a VirtualBox VDI during this test. The whole time it will use one processor and switch to the next one every minute or so. If I try to open Firefox or the file browser it will run so sluggish with major lag. This machine can't do more then 1 thing at a time...

Your help would be great!

P.S. Just clicking on About This Computer took about 40 seconds to open.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this behaviour only in virtualbox ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something setup incorrectly. Easiest solution is to back up all of your files, wipe the disk clean (ie: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/[disk]` clean), and then reinstall Ubuntu.